# Rcolorbrewer and ggplot2 R: colormap for geom_hex

Tags: r, matplotlib, ggplot2, seaborn

I would like to make this type of figure below in R, which is a combination of marginal histograms and a geom_hex object I think. This is originally a matplotlib seaborn graph.

I can't get it to talk to RColorbrewer. Any thoughts why?

[image]

So far I've got:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(RColorBrewer)
require(ggExtra)
bl<-data.frame(beta=rnorm(100),lambda=rnorm(100))

p<-ggplot(bl,aes(x=beta,y=lambda))+
  stat_bin_hex()+
  #scale_fill_gradient(palette = "Greens") Neither of these work
  #scale_fill_continuous(palette = "Greens")+
  scale_fill_brewer()+
  theme_classic()


  ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram")
```

Original code:

```
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 1000).T
with sns.axes_style("white"):
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html

```
sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, kind="hex", color="greens");
```

Comment: You need to assign a variable to the fill. You do this inside your `aes` call. The usage section on the front page of the `ggplot2` docs gives an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_gradientn` and pass in the palette using `brewer.pal`.  Then you just need to pass in the right fill and color to `ggMarginal`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggExtra)

bl <- data.frame(beta=rnorm(10000),lambda=rnorm(10000))

p <- ggplot(bl, aes(x=beta, y = lambda))+
  stat_bin_hex() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Greens")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram", fill = brewer.pal(3,"Greens")[1], color = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Great! Without `RColorBrewer` it's possible to do inside `state_binhex`. Like this `stat_binhex(aes(alpha=..count..), fill="forestgreen")`

Comment: You can make it darker by changing the values passed in `scale_color_gradientn`.